# Signal handler for all signal

Tags: c, linux, unix, signal-handling

How can I register a signal handler for ALL signal, available on the running OS, using signal(3)?

My code looks like this:

```
void sig_handler(int signum)
{
    printf("Received signal %d\n", signum);
}


int main()
{
    signal(ALL_SIGNALS_??, sig_handler);
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `for` loop, from 1 to 31?

Comment: Each system has a list of signals. See `/usr/include/signal.h` There is no single standard macro you can use to represent all of them.  Plus.  You cannot trap all of them, `SIGKILL` for example.

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned that. But on some mordern OS are having more than 32. kill -l on FreeBSD for example returns 126 entries.

Comment: Then you should check on which Platform you are... But I don't think you need them all, SIGINT, SIGUSR1/2 and a few more should be enough.
btw. in /usr/include/bits/signum.h you find all with their description.

Comment: okay I have to consider mac os x and freeBSD, I will just use a for loop that counts to the OS specific signal count. Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: You cannot use printf() in a signal handler. (it is non-reentant)

Comment: @wildplasser: Actually in this program it's perfectly valid to use `printf` in the signal handler. The restriction on using non-async-signal-safe functions in signal handlers only applies if the signal interrupts a non-AS-safe function. All the functions called from `main` in this program are AS-safe, so the signal handler can use any functions it wants. Of course this analysis only applies to the sample program in the question; it likely does not apply to OP's actual program.

Comment: @R and what happens if a signal arrives while the printf is being executed within the signal handler?  (Hint: bad things)  It is not safe to call printf in a signal handler, even in this simple program.

Comment: Read *carfully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Some signals (e.g. `SIGKILL`) *cannot be caught*.

Answer (score 7):

Most systems have a macro `NSIG` or `_NSIG` (the former would not be available in standards-conformance mode since it violates the namespace) defined in `signal.h` such that a loop `for (i=1; i<_NSIG; i++)` will walk all signals. Also, on POSIX systems that have signal masks, `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(sigset_t)` is an upper bound on the number of signals which you could use as a fallback if neither `NSIG` nor `_NSIG` is defined.

Comment: source: [*24.2 Standard Signals - The GNU C Library*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Signals.html)

Comment: But I don't understand why not `i = 0` but `i = 1`. According to the explanation in the link above, the value of `NSIG` corresponds both to the number of signals defined and to `<largest signal number> + 1`, which implies that the signal number starts with `0`. I suspect your code is intentional so could you give me an explanation? (Maybe [*What does `kill -0` do?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169898/what-does-kill-0-do) is related?)

Answer (score 3):

Signal handlers have to deal with reentrancy concerns and other problems.  In practice, it's often more convenient to mask signals and then retrieve them from time to time.  You can mask all signals (except `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL`, which you can't handle anyway) with this:

```
sigset_t all_signals;
sigfillset(&all_signals);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &all_signals, NULL);
```

The code is slightly different if you're using pthreads.  Call this in every thread, or (preferably) in the main thread before you create any others:

```
sigset_t all_signals;
sigfillset(&all_signals);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &all_signals, NULL);
```

Once you've done that, you should periodically call `sigtimedwait(2)` like this:

```
struct timespec no_time = {0, 0};
siginfo_t result;
int rc = sigtimedwait(&all_signals, &result, &no_time);
```

If there is a signal pending, information about it will be placed in `result` and `rc` will be the signal number; if not, `rc` will be -1 and `errno` will be `EAGAIN`.  If you're already calling `select(2)`/`poll(2)` (e.g. as part of some event-driven system), you may want to create a [`signalfd(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd) instead and attach it to your event loop.  In this case, you still need to mask the signals as shown above.